# Calculator shows incorrect result for 32-bit subtraction?

Tags: arduino, math

I was trying to [argue](https://forum.arduino.cc/t/dont-use-millis-or-micros-or-delay-or-even-delaymicroseconds-in-your-project) about the operation of a routine called micros() and millis() that is used on the Arduino platform, and I ended up finding this [calculator](https://calc.penjee.com/). The calculator shows a different result than 8-bit (ATmega328 - Arduino Nano) and 32-bit (ESP32) processors. They even cited the result of the Windows calculator, which shows the same result as the aforementioned microcontrollers.

> Nano/ESP32: 0x1 - 0xFFFFFF00 = 0x101

> Calculator: 0x1 - 0xFFFFFF00 = 0xFFFFFEFF

I found an [explanation](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/22145/how-is-subtraction-performed-on-unsigned-numbers-within-the-cpu) for calculating subtraction for 8-bit numbers,

**Does anyone know of an answer made with 32-bit numbers?**.

Comment: Is `0xFFFFFF00` supposed to be `4294967040` or -256?

Comment: @IgorSkochinsky, Hi, this is my doubt. Apparently, a microcontroller accepts one thing, but a calculator accepts something else. They commented that in Linux the result is the same as in the microcontroller, so I ended up not being able to argue anymore.